# Research about effects of text formatting on cognitive load when reading?

Tags: reading, cognitive-load

Note: I've posted a [version of this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/143417/116190) on ux.stackexchange.com and have been advised to also try here.

Has anyone come across peer-reviewed research on the effect of text formatting on cognitive load? I'm more particularly interested on wider evidence about whether working with column width, one can compensate for the difficulty of texts that use lengthy paragraphs that render them more difficult to comprehend.

I haven't seen related questions here, but on UX I've found [this one](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3618/ideal-column-width-for-paragraphs-online). However, even the most researched answers there limit themselves to providing some web links.

I've also looked up some research on the topic, but whereas [(1)](https://doi.org/10.1145/1498700.1498704) and [(2)](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.chb.2007.02.015) were insightful, they didn't address specifically my question

Comment: This seems interesting, and I don't know much about the theory behind this, but I still want to share some ideas. This seems to be related to the easiness of reading and loading a text into short term memory for processing. The cognitive load of understanding the text seems to be mainly related to how the text is written. Understanding a text seems like a different mechanism than reading and loading that text for processing. With that said, the text formatting must allow for a pleasant reading experience, and that in itself could be unique for every person.